# The named parameter 'body' isn't defined. error

Tags: flutter, dart

for Body:TabBarView line gives this error. Android studio offers to use key: but it makes same problem. I am really newbie, please forgive me if the question is not logic.

```
 Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
          10.0,
        ),
        child: FutureBuilder<Categories>(
          future: _futureCategory,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Categories> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final category = snapshot.data?.data;

              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: category!.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, id) {
                  return DefaultTabController(
                  length: 6,
                  child: AppBar(
                    centerTitle: true,
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.person_outline),
                    bottom: const PreferredSize(
                        child: TabBar(
                          isScrollable: true,
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(
                              child: Text('Tab'),
                    ),

                          ],
                        ),
                        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(30.0)),
                  actions: const <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                  child: Icon(Icons.add_alert),
                  )

                  ]
                  ),
                      body: TabBarView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                  child: const Center(
                  child: Text('Tab 1'),
                  ),
                  ),
    ]));
                }
              );
```

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `appBar` and `body` like that you would have to use a `Scaffold` :

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: yourBody()
)
```

That part of your code will be like this:

```
return DefaultTabController(
    length: 6,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: const Icon(Icons.person_outline),
          bottom: const PreferredSize(
              child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Text('Tab'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(30.0)),
          actions: const <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.add_alert),
            )
          ]),
      body: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: const Center(
            child: Text('Tab 1'),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    ));
```